# Does a class instance thread affinity have any impact on its data?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

We know from the QThread [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity)

> A QObject instance is said to have a thread affinity, or that it lives
>   in a certain thread. When a QObject receives a queued signal or a
>   posted event, the slot or event handler will run in the thread that
>   the object lives in.

Does the thread affinity have any impact on the class instance data? Does the class data become thread data?

Apart from the above, the reason I am asking is because I want to pass a pointer/reference of another class in its constructor. If I am being object oriented, I shall not access its data directly but if I call a member function of the other class, will it also be called in this class's thread?

Comment: The quote doesn't talk about classes but about instances [of classes], which makes me wonder whether you just confused the two. Or, do you want to refer to class-static data, which could be called "class data" as opposed to "instance data".

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I do mean the class object instance like it is in the documentation, not the class itself, I guess I didn't wanted to be too wordy.

Comment: Please go and edit your question to make that clear!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt since you insist, updated my post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the thread affinity has any impact on the class data?

No, a QObject's thread affinity only controls which thread its slot and event handlers run in.

> Does the class data becomes a thread data?

Class data means class static data members - that can't possibly be affected by the thread affinity of each instance. Instance data isn't somehow made thread-local either: thread-local storage can be very limited, and there's simply no reason to force every instance into it.

> Apart from the above ...

If you don't issue a signal or event, normal method calls are just method calls.